# scikit-learn: how to use two different data sets as train and test sets

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use different data sets as train and test sets respectively. But with following code i'm getting:

`File "main.py", line 84, in main_test
    X2 = tf_transformer.transform(word_counts2)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1020, in transform
    n_features, expected_n_features))
ValueError: Input has n_features=1293 while the model has been trained with n_features=1625`

```
def main_test(path = None):
    dir_path = path or 'dataset'
    files = sklearn.datasets.load_files(dir_path)
    util.refine_all_emails(files.data)
    word_counts = util.bagOfWords(files.data)
    tf_transformer = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)
    tf_transformer.fit(word_counts)
    X = tf_transformer.transform(word_counts)

    dir_path = 'testset'
    files2 = sklearn.datasets.load_files(dir_path)
    util.refine_all_emails(files2.data)
    word_counts2 = util.bagOfWords(files2.data)
    # tf_transformer = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)
    # tf_transformer.fit(word_counts2)
    X2 = tf_transformer.transform(word_counts2)

    clf = sklearn.svm.LinearSVC()

    test_classifier(X, files.target, clf, X2, files2.target, test_size=0.2, y_names=files.target_names, confusion=False)


def test_classifier(X, y, clf, X2, y2, test_size=0.4, y_names=None, confusion=False):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X, X2, y, y2
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    # clf.fit(X_test, y_test)
    y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

    print colored('Classification report:', 'magenta', attrs=['bold'])
    print sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_predicted, target_names=y_names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you call

```
word_counts2 = util.bagOfWords(files2.data)
```

It produces results with words which tfidf transformer never seen in training set, and doesn't have inverse frequencies for such words.

You need to produce counts only for words which occurred in training set, maybe [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) will help with it.

Comment: How to do the same in R?